# read key from LocalizedResource.properties programmatically

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, uibinder

I able to use LocalizedResource.properties with uibinder. let say i have widget that created programmatically in java file. how to read in key from LocalizedResource.properties depending on language "en,fr..etc" selected by users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say something definitely.

1. If your LocalizedResource.properties is generated as described by "[Internationalization - UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n.html)" so I don't understand why you want to read in key from it
2. If .properties made for Message or Constant interface so you could read *fr_CA.properties by http://*.html?locale=fr_CA and so for any languge you want.

   Helpful link is [Internationalizing GWT: Creating the translation for each language supported](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n.html#international)
3. or try **@UiTemplate** to switch between tamplates prepared for different languages. To find out current locale you can use `LocaleInfo.getLocaleName()`.

   Helpful link is [Apply different XML templates to the same widget](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Apply_different_xml)

Comment: because i did mentioned, if programatically i create widget, i need to get the .properties directly inside code rather than uibinder.xml

Answer (score 2):

@Paŭlo Ebermann

This method doesn't work for GWT because GWT can't translate java classes like `Locale` and 
 `ResourceBUndle` to JavaScript.

I just try it.

```
Locale loc = new Locale(LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName());
String key = "AnotherWord";
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("msgs", loc);
```

GWT Compilation fail with

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/K:/programming/eclipse-workspace/polyglotte/src/com/mw/uibinder/client/Polyglotte.java'
  [ERROR] Line 64: No source code is available for type java.util.Locale; did you forget to inherit a required module?
  [ERROR] Line 67: No source code is available for type java.util.ResourceBundle; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

May be it will work if I try feed GWT Compiler with java.util.* source codes. But I think it isn't good idea. Why Googlers don't follow this way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about GWT and UIBinder, but in "Standard Edition" Java, you would create a `ResourceBundle` of your selected language (Locale), and then use its `getString` method.

```
Locale loc = ...;
String key = ...;
ResourceBundle bundle =
     ResourceBundle.getBundle("LocalizedResource", loc);

String value = bundle.getString(key);
```

Then you can use this string to label your widget.

Please try this and report the success in GWT.